# will multiple sleep in mysql creates any issue?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I am using ODK for my project and I am having 3 instances right now. When I view the processess in mysql phpmyadmin, I can see many of the process is in sleep by the different ODK instance.

Is having multiple sleep creates any performance issue?

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/02/08/debugging-sleeping-connections-with-mysql/

Comment: you can also set the `wait_timeout=30` in your config file. Then the connections will die after 30 seconds unless they are used again.